# Efficient way to sample per group with given number/proportions in R

Tags: r, random, group-by

I would like to know if there's an efficient way of sampling for groups, choosing an integer and/or proportion to sample from them. I am aware of the existence of `sample_n` and that it works with grouped dfs but as far as I know it samples the same number for each group.

A minimal description of the problem, on a simple case, would be to sample, from the dataframe `mpg`, 5 random rows (or vector of indexes of those rows) for `cyl == 4`, 7 for `cyl == 6` and 3 for `cyl == 8`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `sampling::strat()` function. The `size` argument is a vector of counts. The documentation says

> "size = vector of stratum sample sizes (in the order in which the strata are
> given in the input data set)."

```
library(sampling)

# filter to the groups of interest
dat <- mpg[mpg$cyl %in% c(4, 6, 8),]

# vector of counts for each group (in the order those groups appear in the data)
strata <- strata(data = dat, stratanames="cyl", size = c(5,7,3) , method = "srswor")

# use the 'ID_unit' vector to subset the original data
dat[strata$ID_unit,]
```